# POST, PUT, DELETE in Django RESTful framework not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, request

I'd like to post to my Django server using POST so I can add a employee item.

views.py

```
class EmployeeList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer


class EmployeeDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
```

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    lastname=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    emp_id=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname;
```

serializer.py

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Employee
        # fields={'firstname','lastname'}
        fields='__all__'
```

My POST request:

```
{
    "id": 8,
    "firstname": "zxcvb",
    "lastname": "bnmmm",
    "emp_id": 3
}
```

Error I got:

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
}
```

Even after using `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` I can't POST, PUT or DELETE.

PS: I’m new to Django REST framework.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a `post` method handler you'll need a view with a `create()` action (`CreateAPIView` or `ListCreateAPIView`). Check the documention about [concrete view classes](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#concrete-view-classes).

Change your `EmployeeList` view to inherit from `ListCreateAPIView` for add read-write endpoints to represent a collection of employees

```
class EmployeeList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
```

Now, just register the views with the URL conf as usual

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('employees/', EmployeeList, name='employee-list'),
    path('employees/<int:pk>/', EmployeeDetail, name='employee-detail'),
]
```

Concrete view classes map methods defined in mixins such `ListModelMixin`, `CreateModelMixin`, `RetrieveModelMixin`, etc. to HTTP methods. By defaults, theese actions (see [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions)) are mapped to the following HTTP methods

- `list` - `get`
- `create` - `post`
- `retrieve` - `get`
- `update` - `put`
- `partial_update` - `patch`
- `destroy` - `delete`